# pipe output of "script" command _without_ buffering

Tags: shell, unix

I am capturing some terminal session output (using the "script" command) for testing.
The script command works great, gets everything no matter what, even sub-shells and remote login sessions.  However, it would be really useful to know WHEN things happened, so I'd like to have a timestamp on each line of the output of script.  Unfortunately, script doesn't use stdout (for obvious reasons), so I can't just pipe it to, say, ts.  I also doesn't recognize any form of the special '-' file name.

I'd like to do something like this: > script `|ts > foo`
Where script would open "|ts > foo" as a file, but writes to it would go through the pipe
to ts, which itself would redirect to file foo.

Is there any shell syntax or trickery to do this? (prefer ksh, can use bash.)

The only thing I could come up with was to use a named pipe, but that may have buffering
issues, and seems really clumsy for this use.

BTW I used the script command because regular stdout capture doesn't get all the terminal interaction.  As far as I can tell, it's the only command which does that.

Comment: OK, someone pointed me to the oxymoronic "anonymous named pipes" feature. So I can do this: `ts()
{
        while read A
        do
                echo "$(date) $A"
        done
}
script >(ts > $1)` But now all the timestamps are the same, because all the output is buffered up and processed at once.  What to do?

Comment: Which version of `script` do you use? --- The `script` from the [util-linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux) package has ability to record timestamps (though they are relative to each other) or to flush after each wite. See [Linux man script](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) --- The `script` from BSD Unixes allows specification of the flushing interval (down to 0) and a recording with timestamps too. See [FreeBSD man scipt](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=script&sektion=1). --- Overriding the buffering requires some kind of intervention into the program.

Comment: The script command that comes on the system doesn't support those options (Solaris unix).  The easiest thing to do, I guess, would be to port over the linux version.